# what is this sequence of chars in symbolic execution?

Tags: arrays, char, smt, angr, symbolic-execution

I am using Angr, a framework for symbolic execution. It only accepts 'read' function in C for getting input.
It solves a program in C and converts its symbolic value to concrete value and I get this on its output: 
[image: this is my output]

it is actually the value of char[8] variable that is being read by read(0, input, 8)
But i don't know what is the value of input at the end.

Please help me.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what type of encoding you use. But it seems that \x80 is a special character (control character).
Symbolic Execution engines usually show char arrays by a list of integers, since every character is an integer at the end.